# Where does raspistill save the thumbnails?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam

I am trying to create a timelapse with `raspistill`. What I would need is to have a thumbnail image as well.

Reading the documentation I've found that you can use the `--thumb` flag to specify thumbnail sizes. But I don't know where they are saved

I am using the following command:

```
raspistill \
    --verbose \
    -t 0 \
    -tl 1000 \
    --thumb 320:240:70 \
    -n \
    -o imgs/image%04d.jpg
```

## Solution

(thanks to Peter)

1. Install exiv2

   ```
   sudo apt-get install exiv2
   ```
2. Use the command below to extract the thumbnail from `image0000.jpg` to `image0000-thumb.jpg`

   ```
   exiv2 -et ./image0000.jpg
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the thumbnail gets embedded into the JPEG image as EXIF data. Exiftool allows you to view the embedded thumbnail images - http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Exiftool.